# How do I express this equation in Autohotkey to keep the zeroes

Tags: expression, addition, autohotkey

I am trying figure out how to keep adding 100 to a variable but keep the zeroes in place. Here is what I mean.

```
A = 0001
msgbox % (a + 100)
```

The way it is now gives me "101" instead of "0101". Eventually I want to be able to keep adding 100 to get: 0101, 0201...1001...2101...and so forth.

Answer (score 2):

**Displays numeric value padded to length 4 by prefixing 0's**

```
a := 1
msgbox % format( "{1:04}", a + 100 )
```

**Message Box Output**

```
0101
```

**Notes**

- `1` refers to the first argument (a+100)
- `:04` defines format: width 4 padded by 0's
- [Format](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Format.htm) Reference